# couldn't I open spring boot web?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, web

Before running as Java app, my project has MySql, Spring-boot, REST service.
I would like to deploy web app but system reported errmessage: Whitelabel Error Page...

[image]

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/autoeshop")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

    /* to save an employee*/
    @PostMapping("/employees")
    public Employee saveEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody Employee emp) {
        return employeeDAO.save(emp);
    }

    /*get an employee by id*/
    @GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployee(@PathVariable(value="id") Long empId){
        Employee emp=employeeDAO.get(empId);

        if(emp==null)
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(emp);
    }   

    /*get all employees*/
    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(){
        return employeeDAO.getAll();
    }

    /*update an employee*/
    @PutMapping("/employees")
    public void updateEmployee(@PathVariable(value="id") Long empId, @Valid @RequestBody Employee empDetails) {

        Employee emp = employeeDAO.get(empId);
        //if(emp==null)
        //  return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();

        emp.setName(empDetails.getName());
        emp.setDesignation(empDetails.getDesignation());
        emp.setExpertise(empDetails.getExpertise());

        //return ResponseEntity.ok().body((Employee)employeeDAO.update(emp));
        employeeDAO.update(emp);
    }

    /*Delete an employee*/
    @DeleteMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> deleteEmployee(@PathVariable(value="id") Long empId){
        //Employee emp=employeeDAO.get(empId);

        if(employeeDAO.get(empId)==null)
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        employeeDAO.delete(empId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

application.properties:

> ### Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
>
> ```
> spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/autoeshop
> spring.datasource.username = root
> spring.datasource.password =
>
>
>
> ## Hibernate Properties
> # The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
>
> # Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
> ```

Please tell me for helping how can I deploy web app? Thanks

Comment: can you post your controller code ? is the url ok ?

Comment: And how can we tell without actual controller code where all paths are configured??:>

Comment: 404 not found: you're trying to access a URL that is not handled by your application. If you think it should be, then post the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

The application is actually deployed:

In spring boot, only when the application starts (the application context starts) successfully, the http port gets exposed (8081 in your case)

However, there is no mapping of `/autoeshop/employee` registered in the application.
You can check the startup log of spring application, it logs all the registered mappings.

Now if there is no mapping, the default behavior is to return this error page + http 404 (not found) status, and thats exactly what you see.

So bottom line, you should check the controller mappings, it will probably boil down to one of the following:

- Controller has different mappings specified with annotations that you're trying to check
- Spring boot didn't find your controller (there are many possible reasons for this)

**Update:** I've seen your code now and indeed there is no mapping of GET request to 
`/autoeshop/employee`

Instead you have a mapping to `/autoeshop/employees` (plural)

```
 /*get all employees*/
@GetMapping("/employees")
public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(){
    return employeeDAO.getAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ohhh, I forget to put my codes.

Controller:

```
package com.autoparts.autoeshop.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.autoparts.autoeshop.dao.EmployeeDAO;
import com.autoparts.autoeshop.model.Employee;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/autoeshop")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

    /* to save an employee*/
    @PostMapping("/employees")
    public Employee saveEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody Employee emp) {
        return employeeDAO.save(emp);
    }

    /*get an employee by id*/
    @GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployee(@PathVariable(value="id") Long empId){
        Employee emp=employeeDAO.get(empId);

        if(emp==null)
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(emp);
    }   

    /*get all employees*/
    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(){
        return employeeDAO.getAll();
    }

    /*update an employee*/
    @PutMapping("/employees")
    public void updateEmployee(@PathVariable(value="id") Long empId, @Valid @RequestBody Employee empDetails) {

        Employee emp = employeeDAO.get(empId);
        //if(emp==null)
        //  return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();

        emp.setName(empDetails.getName());
        emp.setDesignation(empDetails.getDesignation());
        emp.setExpertise(empDetails.getExpertise());

        //return ResponseEntity.ok().body((Employee)employeeDAO.update(emp));
        employeeDAO.update(emp);
    }

    /*Delete an employee*/
    @DeleteMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> deleteEmployee(@PathVariable(value="id") Long empId){
        //Employee emp=employeeDAO.get(empId);

        if(employeeDAO.get(empId)==null)
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        employeeDAO.delete(empId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/autoeshop
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 
server.port=8081



## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Comment: Your url should end with `employees`. So final url  `localhost:8081/autoeshop/employees`

Comment: You better update the question because this is not an answer actually, you can edit a question instead and add code snippets there